# Getting error of instance path in FLASK-SQLALCHEMY( Python )

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

ERROR:

```
 File "<frozen os>", line 225, in makedirs
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Program Files\\JetBrains\\PyCharm 2023.1.2\\jbr\\bin\\instance'
```

I want this to create an automatically instance path in which my database file will be stored

```py
# **small piece of  main.py  creating database in sqlalchemy:**
        from flask import Flask
        from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
        from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
        import os
    
        app = Flask(__name__, instance_path=os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'instance'))
    
        app.config\['SECRET_KEY'\] = '8BYkEfBA6O6WlSihBXox7C0sKR6b'
        Bootstrap(app)
    
    # CREATE DB
    
        app.config\['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'\] = 'sqlite:///movies.db'
        app.config\['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'\] = False
        db = SQLAlchemy(app)
    
    # CREATE TABLE
    
        class Movie(db.Model):
        id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
        title = db.Column(db.String(250), unique=True, nullable=False)
        year = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
        description = db.Column(db.String(500), nullable=False)
        rating = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=True)
        ranking = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=True)
        review = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=True)
        img_url = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
    
        db.create_all()
```

Answer (score 1):

Running a Flask application might face permission issues when trying to create directories in certain system locations, especially in ‘Program Files.’ Consider changing the instance path to a location where your user has write permissions, such as your user directory.

For example:

```
app = Flask(__name__, instance_path=os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), 'your_app_instance'))
```

Replace ‘`your_app_instance`’ with the desired directory name. This should help resolve the permission error.